# How to select what sprite or texture to render first?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm making a game using libgdx and I encountered a problem when rendering textures

```
batch.draw(background, x, y, width, height);
sprite.draw(batch); //of course the background will be rendered first
```

And when I do this:

```
 sprite.draw(batch);
 batch.draw(background, x, y, width, height); //the background will cover the sprite
```

My problem is that I use two cameras, on is static and the other is non-static. So I need a way on how to select which sprite or texture to be rendered first so that it wont be covered by other textures.

Comment: Personnally, all my game objects are into an array and have both a render method and an int to define their priority. I just have to sort the array with the ints before calling all the render methods.

Comment: I don't understand the question. They are drawn in the order you draw them like you demonstrated.

Comment: Yes but how do I draw them in the order that I want and not in order based on the line of code, because I'm using multiple camera.